# How to execute cypher query after another query has completed in NodeJS?

Tags: reactjs, neo4j, cypher

I have a ReactJS-neo4j application which has following function :

```
const myFunction = async function( req, res ){
    const session = driver.session( { database:process.env.REACT_APP_NEO4J_DB } );
    const txc = session.beginTransaction();
    let result = null;

    try{
        
        result = await txc.run( 
            `MATCH (n {id: $data1}), (m {id: $data2})
               
                WITH head(collect([n,m])) as nodes
                CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes,{properties:"discard", mergeRels: true})
                YIELD node
                RETURN node`, 
            { 
              'data1':data1, 
              'data2':data2 
            }
        )
        
        await txc.commit();
    }

    catch(error){
        await txc.rollback()
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err, message: "Error" })
    }
    finally{
        await session.close();
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: result })
    }
}
```

It executes one cypher query. Now I have to execute another cypher query after this query has completed. My second query is

```
            `MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
                SET r.sourceData=n.id, r.targetData=m.id`
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: add your additional query to the first query. thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy how ?? Could you please notice the update and give explanation ?

Comment: btw, you are doing a DISCARD so m will be removed since it is replaced by n.  Thus when you do a match (n)-(m), it will be empty and r is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The merge node is a 'discard', thus node n will replace m and m is removed. I propose an alternate solution wherein all relationships connected to n will have the properties, sourceData and targetData.

```
MATCH (n {id: $data1}), (m {id: $data2})
WITH m.id as targetId, head(collect([n,m])) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes,{properties:"discard", mergeRels:true})
YIELD node
//node returns n since mergeNodes is a 'discard'
MATCH (node)-[r]-()
//search all edges connected to n and update source and target data
SET r.sourceData=node.id, r.targetData=targetId
RETURN node
```